# Wishlist added products icon not active in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, wishlist, visibility, icon

Wishlist added products icon not active or color change in product detail page and listing. But added products are present in "MY WISH LIST" in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url, I hope its work for you.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11825